# file upload with index array

Tags: php, arrays

I have file type input.

```
<input name="maintenance_request[file0]" type="file">
```

After uploading I am trying to print the variable data.

```
print_r( $_FILES );
```

After printing for array contents it shows the file0 index inside each of FILES array value.
It output me as

```
Array(
[maintenance_request] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [file0] => 44.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [file0] => image/jpeg
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [file0] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpB2C6.tmp
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [file0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [file0] => 42923
            )

    ))
```

I want array like this -

```
Array(
    [maintenance_request] => Array(
            [file0] => Array(
                [name] => 44.jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpFBF8.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 42923
            )
    )
)
```

Where Am I wrong to get the desired array?

Answer (score 0):

It's the expected output for default php functionality..however you can write custom function to sanitizer the array in form you want like below :

```
<?php

function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

?>
```

Then u can do the following:

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['upload']) {
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);

    foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
        print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];
        print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'];
        print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'];
    }
}

?>
```